# Jquery Trigger event when JSON .each is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have the following code to ping a list of computers with Jquery and asp.net.

```
function ping() {
    $('#progress').css("display", "");
    $('.comp').each(function () {
        var $computer = $(this);            
        $.getJSON('pingcomputer.aspx', { computer: $(this).attr("rel") }, function (data) {
            if (data.Status == '1') {
                $($computer).attr("src", "ok.png");
            }
            else {
                $($computer).attr("src", "nok.png");
            }
        })
    })
    $('#progress').css("display", "none");
}
```

The pinging works fine.
Before the ping start I want to make #progress visible (an image)
After all computers are pinged I want to hide it again.

The problem is that the #progress image is immediately hidden when the function is called.
How can I detect when all "pingcomputer.aspx" pages have finished loading?

Comment: try setting z-index. maybe it's getting hidden behind something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a counter which checks that  as many requests have been completed as there was started:

```
function ping() {
    $('#progress').css("display", "");
    var count = 0,
        total = $(".comp").length;
    $('.comp').each(function () {
        var $computer = $(this);     

        $.getJSON('pingcomputer.aspx', { computer: $(this).attr("rel") }, function (data) {
            count++;     
            if (data.Status == '1') {
                $($computer).attr("src", "ok.png");
            }
            else {
                $($computer).attr("src", "nok.png");
            }
            if (count==total) $('#progress').css("display", "none");
        })
    })

}
```

Comment: Dammit, I tried this already but I added  if (count==total) $('#progress').css("display", "none");just before the end of the function instead of inside the getJSON function.

Comment: @WilfriedVS That will obviously not work as `count` will be 0 when the function reaches its end, as none of the requests have finished at that point :)

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of things that should happen, decrement the count each time one thing does. When there are none left, stop the progress bar.  BTW, any reason you're not using show()/hide()?

```
function ping() {
    $('#progress').show();
    var $comp = $('.comp'),
        waitCount = $(comp).length;
    $comp.each(function () {
        var $computer = $(this);            
        $.getJSON('pingcomputer.aspx', { computer: $(this).attr("rel") }, function (data) {
            if (data.Status == '1') {
                $($computer).attr("src", "ok.png");
            }
            else {
                $($computer).attr("src", "nok.png");
            }
            if (--waitCount == 0) {
               $('#progress').hide();
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: pingcomputer.aspx returns 0 if the computer is not available

Comment: @WilfriedVS - nevermind.  I didn't read closely enough.  I thought you were calling a page on each computer to get the request directly.  If you're calling a page on the web server that returns the result of a ping, then you're probably ok not checking for AJAX errors.